# Do all bilinear forms have a signature?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, multilinear-algebra, bilinear-form

**If yes**: starting from any arbitrary bilinear form, what is the algorithm to calculate its signature?

**If no**: what are the conditions necessary for a bilinear form in order to have a signature? Is there an algorithm to calculate a signature for all the bilinear forms that admit one?

Comment: Why you think not all of the bilinear forms do not have their signature?

Comment: You need more details for this question. Bilinear forms over what fields? What kind of bilinear forms? Classically, the definition is for symmetric bilinear forms over ordered fields. I guess one can define the signature of an arbitrary bilinear form over an ordered field as the signature of its symmetric part, but I'm not sure that is very common.

Comment: @CaptainLama i have updated my question after your feedback. my question is in general, for arbitrary forms, but if no such algorithm exists for all of them, i am interested in knowing which subset of bilinear forms admit a signature, and if there is an algorithm for this subset

Comment: see  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

Comment: @CaptainLama do all symmetric bilinear form over ordered fields admit a signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $b: V\times V\to K$ be a finite-dimensional symmetric bilinear form over some field $K$ (let us say of characteristic not $2$). Then it can be diagonalized, meaning that there is a basis $(e_i)$ of $V$ such that the matrix $(b(e_i,e_j))_{i,j}\in M_n(K)$ is diagonal. If $a_i=b(e_i,e_i)$, we then write
$$b \simeq \langle a_1,\dots,a_n\rangle. $$

The $a_i$ in this diagonalization are absolutely not unique, not even up to reordering: at the very least, you can multiply any $a_i$ by some non-zero square in $K$. On the other hand, there is somethign which is well-defined: the number of $a_i$ which are equal to $0$. That is the dimension of the radical of $b$, and it does not depend on the choice of diagonalization. If that dimension happens to be $0$, we say that $b$ is non-degenerate.

When $K$ is an ordered field, we can say more: the number of $a_i$ which are positive (respectively negative) is also well-defined, independently of the choice of diagonalization. Then the triplet $(r,p,q)\in \mathbb{N}^3$ where $r$ is the number of $a_i$ which are $0$, and $p$ (resp. $q$) is the number of $a_i>0$ (resp. $a_i<0$) does not depend on the diagonalization, and is (often) called the signature of $b$. It always exists when $K$ is an oredered field, and can be computed by diagonalizing $b$ (which can be done in a number of ways, there are probably about 5000 questions on this website on the subject), and then checking the signs of the $a_i$.

Note that the precise terminology might differ depending on the author, for instance what I usually call the signature of $b$ is rather the number $p-q\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Also note that if $K$ is just a field, with no distinguished order, what you can do is define the signature of $b$ at each ordering of $K$ (there might be none of course, that happens precisely when $-1$ is a sum of squares in $K$).